# Using GNSDK within a Video Camera Mobile Application

Tags: gracenote

Is it possible to use the GNSDK recognition feature within a video camera application? Ie, starting to record a video would concurrently trigger the GNSDK recognition function.

Answer (score 0):

GNSDK does not work with video. You need to feed decoded audio stream to GNSDK. As long as you provide the correct audio data, when or how you start the recognition is totally up to you, the developer.